# How can I use enqueue() in java with an Key object?

Tags: java, queue

Here is the line that shows an error

```
if (cmplo <= 0 && cmphi >= 0) queue.enqueue(x.key);
```

where

```
Queue<Key> queue = new  LinkedList<Key>();
```

and `x.key` is an object from Key type.

The error said:

> cannot find symbol method enqueue(Key)

Any suggestion to fix such error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`java.util.Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) doesn't have such method. Instead, it has [`offer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#offer-E-) method to add data.